Excel formulae to use conditional formatting each cell in a column which is < or > than the 4th column to the right of that cell
I have a spreadsheet where each cell in each column is compared to the value on the same row in the 4th column from the right and should the value be greater or smaller the font colour is changed accordingly. Therefore if...
Column A1 </> E1 format font red/green 
Column B1 </> F1 format font red/green
Column C1 </> G1 format font red/green

it then goes on as E1 </> I1 etc... up to column AW
I cannot figure out the formulae to use to avoid have to repeat the basic </> option in conditional formatting, it would be quicker to manually do it.

You need only two rules for the entire range: one for the red font, and another for the green one:
=A1<E1
=A1>E1  

It's not too much, I hope.


Indeed, it is amazing how we can sometimes totally overlook the most simple and obvious of answers. Thank you, I definitely overcomplicated a this in my head.
